# Shortest way to get display value from wpf combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

To get the currently displayed value from a WPF combobox, I am getting `GetSelectedItem` (which gives me a `dataRowView` since my `itemSource` is a `DataView`) and then getting the appropriate column.

I was hoping there could be straightforward way to get the Display Value like how we have the `SelectedValue` property.

Is anyone aware of a better approach?

Comment: Define "value" here.  You already have the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` properties.  If you want the data as it is displayed by your templates, couldn't you just get the data through the "selected" properties the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the ADO.Net class DataTable, right?

You can set a displayed value quite straightforward:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="SomeColumn"
          SelectedValuePath="SomeColumn"/>
```

In this example the combobox displays the value of the column `SomeColumn`. Put a correct column name instead of this dummy one.

And in code-behind:

```
myComboBox.DataContext = myDataSet.Customers; //any table
var selectedValue = myComboBox.SelectedValue;    //The displayed value (SomeColumn)
var fullRow = myComboBox.SelectedITem;        //dataRowView, I think
```

Comment: @cagespear You need to set the same string to the properties DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath, and after that use the SelectedValue property, not the SelectedItem.

Comment: Marking it as answer since it helped me after all. It was one of the ques I posted when I was really naive in WPF and feel kind off stupid to see my own question after an year of hands on WPF programming :)